# Generating Alphanumeric random string in Java

Tags: java, string, random, alphanumeric

I am using String Builder from another answer, but I can't use anything but alpha/numeric, no whitespace, punctuation, etc.  Can you explain how to limit the character set in this code?  Also, how do I insure it is ALWAYS 30 characters long?

```
     Random generator = new Random();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int Length = 30;
    char tempChar ;
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++){
        tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
        stringBuilder.append(tempChar);
```

I have looked at most of the other answers, and can't figure out a solution to this.
Thanks.  Don't yell at me if this is a duplicate.  Most of the answers don't explain which part of the code controls how long the generated number is or where to adjust the character set.

I also tried stringBuilder.Replace(' ', '1'), which might have worked, but eclipse says there is no method for Replace for StringBuilder.

Comment: *"Most of the answers don't explain which part of the code controls how long the generated number is or where to adjust the character set."* ... pointing out the obvious is usually considered rude.

Comment: I knew there would be people who would take umbrage with this question.  Sorry if I offended, but the answers below have definitely added to the wealth and depth of knowledge available on the site.  I do not think this is a duplicate, since the answers have more detailed explanations of the process.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to control the characterset and length take for example

```
public static String randomString(char[] characterSet, int length) {
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    char[] result = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        // picks a random index out of character set > random character
        int randomCharIndex = random.nextInt(characterSet.length);
        result[i] = characterSet[randomCharIndex];
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```

and combine with

```
char[] CHARSET_AZ_09 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
```

to specify the characterset.

It's not based on `StringBuilder` since you know the length and don't need all the overhead.

It allocates a `char[]` array of the correct size, then fills each cell in that array with a randomly chosen character from the input array.

more example use here: http://ideone.com/xvIZcd

Comment: Thanks for ignoring the naysayers.  This worked perfectly!

Comment: @PrivusGuru btw the code you posted generates numbers between `(0..95) + 32` => `32..127`. The characters that correspond to those numbers are here http://www.asciitable.com/ for example. Doing it the way your code does would mean limiting the random numbers to `48..57 OR 65..90 OR 97..122` which would be rather painful. (or you discard characters that are not in that range like e.g. @Sello proposed)

Comment: @zapl is it collision free?

Comment: @Virtu No, it's random. That includes generating the same string 10 times in a row, although with very small probability.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I use:

```
public static String randomStringOfLength(int length) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (buffer.length() < length) {
        buffer.append(uuidString());
    }

    //this part controls the length of the returned string
    return buffer.substring(0, length);  
}


private static String uuidString() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
    //piece
    int i = 0;
    while(i < length){
      char temp =(char) (generator.nextInt(92)+32);
      if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(temp))
      {
        stringBuilder.append(temp);
        ++i;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
```

Should achieve your goal

Comment: Thank you for the time and info.  I will use this somewhere.